# Как называется метод в Qt,который вызывается при нажатии на имя столбца в tableview?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, tableview, обработка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данном случае при нажатии,например на City

Answer (score 2):

[void QAbstractItemView::clicked(const QModelIndex &index)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#clicked)

Comment: А что если я его использую при нажатии на строку столбца,а мне нужно для строки и имени разные обработчики ,то как быть?

Comment: Наверное,я не до конца описал вопрос,прошу простить меня,при нажатии на tableview на строку таблицы, срабатывает этот метод void MainWindow::on_tableView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index),а какой срабатывает при нажатии на имя столбеца

Comment: Хорошо,тогда если я нажимаю на имя City,если изходить из картинки,то row=0 column=3?

Comment: @Nikita, я так понимаю, да, проверьте. Извините, что я удалил комментарий с объяснением, я так понял вы его увидели.

Comment: да,я увидел ваш комментарий

Comment: @Nikita, вы проверили? city это {0,3}?

Comment: ,Да,у них разные все-таки обработчики

Comment: @Nikita и какой обработчик у City?

Comment: Это я и хотел у вас узнать с самого начала :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67738/discussion-between---and-nikita).